# Apply Security To Web service in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have created web service and uploaded on to the server .Now I want to authenticate web service to avoid use of service by other users . How can i apply username and password to block use of service from other users?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
```

On your web method. If you are accessing from the same application.

Other wise you can ask some credential in the message body.

You can user `soap Header` to authenticate user.

Here is a [good link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers)

Comment: that means if session value matches then only web service is accessible for that user. is this my way of thinking is correct?

Comment: Are you accessing for the same application or from the other application also you are allowing?

Comment: accessing for same and other application

Comment: Then you need to SOP Header. Pass the credential in SOP header and check in you code for particular user.

Comment: my problem is,  by entering direct url of web service unable to use any one except admin user by passing correct username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with WCF, there's an easy way to implement security using X509 certificates. Implementing a binding with security mode 'Message' and clientCredentialType 'Username' it's possible to guarantee this security in a automated way.

The validation can be made through a class wich overrides a method Validate.

[How to: Use a Custom User Name and Password Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx)

[Building Secure Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648643.aspx)

[Securing Your ASP.NET Application and Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648667.aspx)

**OR**

you can use of SOAP header to make secure your web service.

Refer below link for SOAP header example.

[Authentication for Web Services (using SOAP headers)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: my problem is,  by entering direct url of web service unable to use any one except admin user by passing correct username and password.

Comment: did you watch  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers link example.